# How to edit Windows .url files

Tags: windows-8, notepad++, url

I have some .url file. I know they are simpy plain text files (cfr. http://www.fmtz.com/formats/url-file-format/article)

But I cant find a way to edit it.

In example, using Notepad++ on Windows 8: clicking Open file, going in the folder where a .url file resides and selecting it happens an odd thing: start a "download" from (I guess) a local temp folder and then I get this error:

[image]

Confusing...

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try dragging the `.url` file, and dropping it in an empty Notepad++ document window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put Notepad into your SendTo folder, then right-click and select Notepad from your `Send To` menu. 
I assume that this would work for Notepad++ too.

Answer (score 2):

As a one time thing, here is an easy way:

1. Open a Windows `"Command Prompt"`
2. Navigate to the folder containing the **`".URL"`** file that you want to edit.
   For this example, let's say your **`".URL"`** file is named **`"Example.url"`**
3. Rename the file to ***add*** a **`".txt"`** extension.
   **`C:\>ren "Example.url" "Example.url.txt"`**
4. Leave the `"Command Prompt"` window open for later.
5. Edit the file in the usual way you would edit a **`".txt"`** file, using your favorite text editor.
6. Return to the open `"Command Prompt"` window.
7. Rename the file back as it was, by removing the **`".txt"`** extension.
   **`C:\>ren "Example.url.txt" "Example.url"`**

If you will be editing **`.URL`** files more often, you can add **`"Notepad.exe"`**, or your favorite text editor, to the **`"context-menu"`** you see when you `"Right Click"` on any **`".URL"`** file.

To do this, you will need to make some simple modifications to your registry. There are a few ways to do this. Here are 2 of them...

**Method 1:**

Create a **`".reg"`** file with the necessary information and use **`"regedit.exe"`** to **`"import"`** the **`".reg"`** file.

First, create a new text document and edit it with your favorite text editor. Copy and paste the following into the file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.AssocFile.URL\Shell\Open URL as Text]
@="Open with Notepad"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.AssocFile.URL\Shell\Open URL as Text\Command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe %1"
```

The above is configured to use **`"Notepad.exe"`** as the editor that will be run when you use your new **`"context-menu"`** item to edit a **`".URL"`** file. If you want to use a different text editor, make these changes to the above new text document before you save it:

1. The part that says **`@="Open with Notepad"`** defines what will show up in the **`"context-menu"`** when you `"Right Click"` on a **`".URL"`** file. You can change it to whatever "title" you want by changing **`"Open with Notepad"`** to **`"Whatever you want"`**.
2. The part that says **`@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe %1"`** defines the program that will be run when you use your new **`"context-menu"`** item to edit a **`".URL"`** file. You can change it to use your favorite text editor by changing **`"C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe"`** to the path and name of your desired text editor. Note that you need to double the backslashes (**`"\"`**) in your path like **`\\`** as shown. Don't forget to leave the ***"space"*** and **`"%1"`** at the end.

If using **`"Notepad"`** is OK with you, then you can leave the file as shown above.

From your text editor, save the new **`".reg"`** file you created. As an example, you could save it as **`"EditURLfile.reg"`**.

Next, run **`"Regedit"`**. It will normally be located here: **`"C:\Windows\regedit.exe"`**.

From within **`"Regedit"`**, click the menu item: **`File`** -> **`Import`**, and navigate to select the select the new **`".reg"`** file you created (**`"EditURLfile.reg"`**) and click **`OK`**.

You can now close **`"Regedit"`**. Now, when you `"Right Click"` on any **`".URL"`** file, you should see a new item in the **`"context-menu"`** to open (**`edit`**) the file.

**Method 2:**

If you are not comfortable using **`"Regedit"`** to add the **`"context-menu"`**, you can do it directly from the Windows `"Command Prompt"`. You will be pasting the following 2 lines into the Windows `"Command Prompt"`:

```
reg add "HKCR\IE.AssocFile.URL\Shell\Open URL as Text" /t REG_SZ /d "Open with Notepad"
reg add "HKCR\IE.AssocFile.URL\Shell\Open URL as Text\Command" /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe %1"
```

The above is configured to use **`"Notepad.exe"`**. If you want to use a different text editor, make these changes to the 2 lines above.

1. The part that says **`"Open with Notepad"`**: Change this to whatever "title" you want for the new **`"context-menu"`** item.
2. The part that says **`"C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe %1"`**: Change this to specify the path and name of your desired text editor. Note that for this method, you need single backslashes (**`"\"`**) in your path as shown. As above, don't forget to leave the ***"space"*** and **`"%1"`** at the end.

If using **`"Notepad"`** is OK with you, then you can leave the 2 lines as shown above.

1. Open a Windows `"Command Prompt"`
   Depending on the `"Policies"` setup on your computer, you may have to open the `"Command Prompt"` as `"Administrator"` (`"Right Click"` on **`"cmd.exe"`** and select . `"Run as Administrator"`).
2. Paste the above 2 lines (one at a time) into the `"Command Prompt"` window.
   For each line you paste, you should get a confirmation message displayed:
   **`The operation completed successfully.`**

Now, when you `"Right Click"` on any **`".URL"`** file, you should see a new item in the **`"context-menu"`** to open (**`edit`**) the file.

Comment: Kevin, you answer is very interesting but I preferred the answer from Scott becasue is very quick to act. But thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For URL files you can just right click them and select "Properties", and in the window select the "Web Document" tab and here you can edit the URL.

EDIT:
If you want to open the actual file to change other things than the actual URL you can just drag and drop the .URL file onto notepad or notepad++.

Comment: I know but it is not enough: I need to access the file as text to edit it like in this doc: http://www.fmtz.com/formats/url-file-format/article

Comment: I've updated my answer, so it also says how to do what you want to do.

Comment: (Thanks for your efforts, Patrick) I tried the drag&drop method but I see a "proibhition icon" when I drag on the window of Notepad++. I tried to open Notepad++ with administrators right but nothing changed. I feel stupid -_-

Answer (score 1):

Right click the file, and then choose "open with notepad".

It is just a text file.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I have this context menu: http://gyazo.com/87f063f179b7adc53092f0301ba54099 No Open with Notepad

Comment: @adriano Right click to the file and then click on properties and then in popup window click on the change and then choose the notepad

Comment: There's not "Change", just "Change icon"

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to open Notepad, then drag the .URL file on the window.

Comment: tried the drag&drop method but I see a "proibhition icon" when I drag on the window of Notepad++. I tried to open Notepad++ with administrators right but nothing changed

Comment: I think it works for Notepad but not Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL file points to a valid file (like a text file) opening directly with notepad will open the shortcut file pointed to. To edit the actual url file, shift + right click on some whitespace in the folder the 'url' file is in (not on an actual file, you want the white space). Click 'open file location in [command prompt/powershell]'.

Once command prompt (or powershell) is open, run

`notepad.exe filenamehere.url`

You can use `dir` first to see the full filename with extension.